# Ubuntu - wireless connection works great but wired is totally dead

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 on my Acer Aspire One netbook.

The wireless connection works great, but the wired is totally dead.

When I plug the Ethernet wire, the little led next to the port doesn't blink.

If I do `ifconfig`, this is the output:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1659 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1659 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:132304 (132.3 KB)  TX bytes:132304 (132.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:f4:6a:65:48:1f  
          inet addr:192.168.1.7  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1af4:6aff:fe65:481f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:94823 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:81390 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:93028474 (93.0 MB)  TX bytes:18002558 (18.0 MB)
```

There is no eth0. Is that normal?

In the "Network Connections" GUI there is an entry "Wired connection 1", its "MAC address" field is blank.

How can I make the wired connection work?

Answer (score 1):

> When I plug the Ethernet wire, the little led next to the port doesn't blink.

The other end of the cable would have to connected to an active port on a switch (or another PC) in order to turn on the "activity" LED.

> If I do ifconfig, this is the output
>     ...
>   There is no eth0. Is that normal?

Try "ifconfig -a", which will report on ***all*** interfaces, rather than just the active ones.

If eth0 is still not listed, then issue a "dmesg" command and review the system log for activity and/or initialization failure of the Ethernet interface.

Answer (score 0):

Acer has its "specifics". Namely I am using boot parameters

```
nohpet hpet=disable
```

to get sky2 netcard up at each boot, and

```
options snd-hda-intel model=acer
```

to get my sound card recording from microphone. Your mileage may vary.